# Deserialize Dictionary with unknown keys with RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp, json-deserialization

I currently am getting a JSON object with a shape similar to the following:

```
{
 more data here...
  "years": {
    "value": 2013,
    "item1": {
      "total": 0.1044,
      "Low": 0.0143,
      "Mid": 0.1044,
      "High": 0.3524,
      "min": 0.0143,
      "max": 0.3524,
    },
    "item2": {
      "total": 0.1702,
      "Low": 0.167,
      "Mid": 0.1702,
      "High": 0.1737,
      "min": 0.167,
      "max": 0.1737,
    },...
  }
}
```

I unfortunately, have no control over the shape of the JSON.

I am trying to get RestSharp to deserialize this into an object where Item1, Item2, and the rest fill into a Dictionary I currently have the following code:

```
public class Year
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Data> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public decimal Low { get; set; }
    public decimal Mid { get; set; }
    public decimal High { get; set; }
    public decimal Min { get; set; }
    public decimal Max { get; set; }
}
```

And I am hoping to get Item1, Item2, etc. to be the keys of the Dictionary and the values underneath to fill in the Data class as the value of the Dictionary. But it isn't working at the moment (the rest of my structure is, it's just this innermost part). Am I just approaching the structure wrong? I want to avoid having to create a specific class for Item1 and Item2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom `JsonConverter`:

```
public class YearConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Year);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);

        int year = (int)obj["value"];
        var data = new Dictionary<string, Data>();

        foreach (var dataItem in obj.Children()
            .OfType<JProperty>()
            .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("item")))
        {
            data.Add(dataItem.Name, dataItem.Value.ToObject<Data>());
        }

        return new Year
        {
            Value = year,
            Data = data
        };
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Decorate your `Year` class with the converter:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(YearConverter))]
public class Year
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Data> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Using it like this, for example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
{
  ""value"": 2013,
  ""item1"": {
    ""total"": 0.1044,
    ""Low"": 0.0143,
    ""Mid"": 0.1044,
    ""High"": 0.3524,
    ""min"": 0.0143,
    ""max"": 0.3524,
  },
  ""item2"": {
    ""total"": 0.1702,
    ""Low"": 0.167,
    ""Mid"": 0.1702,
    ""High"": 0.1737,
    ""min"": 0.167,
    ""max"": 0.1737,
  }
}";
        var years = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Year>(json);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Steps:**
**1. Always shape your JSON object in a logical way**

This issue would be significantly easier to handle if you restructured your json object in a more logical way. Right now you have n number of data objects at the same level as "value" and you are changing their property names dynamically.

Personally, I would reshape the json as such:

```
{
   "years":[
      {
         "value":2013,
         "data":[
            {
               "name":"item1",
               "total":0.1044,
               "Low":0.0143,
               "Mid":0.1044,
               "High":0.3524,
               "min":0.0143,
               "max":0.3524
            },
            {
               "name":"item2",
               "total":0.1702,
               "Low":0.167,
               "Mid":0.1702,
               "High":0.1737,
               "min":0.167,
               "max":0.1737
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**Step 2: Add the Newtonsoft.Json attributes to your classes**

This allows for easy deserialization

```
public class Base
{
    [JsonProperty("years")]
    public List<Year> years { get; set; }
}

    public class Year
    {
        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public int Value { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public List<Data> data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
{
        [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("total")]
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Low")]
        public decimal Low { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Mid")]
        public decimal Mid { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("High")]
        public decimal High { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("min")]
        public decimal Min { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("max")]
        public decimal Max { get; set; }
    }
```

**Step 3: Deserialize it**

```
Base myYears = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Base>(myJsonString);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I probably should have mentioned I have no control over the JSON format, I'll edit that in. I was trying to avoid having to bring in another library but I will keep JSON.Net in mind.

Comment: You can map the incoming JSON to look however you want, so you can easily restructure

Comment: I emphasize restructuring it because I think the model is actually logically broken. Underneath "years", you have a bunch of attributes, unknown names, and one of them is going to be a string and the rest are going to be Data objects. We don't know what the names are going to be, so therefore we can't know what C# variable name to even bind that to. The alternative is to use this: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeCustomCreationConverter.htm You could write custom rules and override the assignments to make it look how you want, I think.

Comment: I am curious how I can remap the JSON without deserializing it. Are you suggesting manipulating the JSON string before use to make it easier to parse? Wouldn't that face similar challenges?

Comment: The link I posted shows how to write custom rules for Json object methods where you can override the regular getters and setters, so theoretically you should be able to combine that with the JsonProperty attributes to fully serialize, I believe. This is one of those times where I wish you were using JavaScript instead of .NET!